# Search for %20 in mySQL database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to search for any rows that contain %20 in my database via phpmyadmin. Here's my query:

```
select * from `jos_picmicro_content` where `introtext` like '\%20' escape '\';
```

Except it returns the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''\'' at line 1
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've escaped the `'`. The correct syntax is:

```
select * from `jos_picmicro_content` where `introtext` like '\%20' escape '\\';
```

In order to identify the problem quickly, divide your query to different rows, e.g.:

```
select * from `jos_picmicro_content` 
where `introtext` 
like '\%20' 
escape '\\';
```

Then MySQL will alert at which row the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably related to MySQL's non-standard usage of the `\` character. But you can specify *any* character with the `ESCAPE` keyword:

```
select * 
from jos_picmicro_content 
where introtext like '@%20' escape '@';
```

But this still won't return anyhting other than rows where introtext is *exactly* `'%20'`, you still need to use a wildcard to find `%20` anywhere in that column:

```
select * 
from jos_picmicro_content 
where introtext like '%@%20%' escape '@';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `escape '\';` part of your query since the default MySQL escape character is '\'. But if you really need the `escape` portion then you have to input it as:

```
escape '\\';
```

Or

```
escape '\\\\';
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try simply:

select * from `jos_picmicro_content` where `introtext` like '%\%20%'